# Trouble converting NSDate with NSDateFormatter

Tags: json, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to convert a date in the format of "2013-02-21T01:25:00.000Z" to something like 1:25AM

```
    NSDate *DepartTimeString = [DepartATime valueForKey:@"dateLocal"];
```

The NSDate is parsed from JSON and shows up as a string on a label fine, but it wont convert to a smaller format using:

```
    NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
    NSString *timeString = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:DepartTimeString];
    NSLog(timeString);
```

The NSLog shows nothing...

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
[timeFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
```

To:

```
[timeFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS"];
```

And check validation **DepartTimeString**